# C# XmlReader, sequence problems

Tags: c#, xml, sequence, xmlreader

This is probably quite noob, but I am having problems with something that is most lightly quite simple. This is my xml:

```
<CustomFieldOptions>
<DataType>Text</DataType>
<Options>
    <Option Key="Advokater">category_advokater</Option>
    <Option Key="Arkitektur- &amp; ingeniørvirksomheder">category_arkitektur</Option>
    <Option Key="Bank &amp; finans">category_bank</Option>
</Options>
```

I am trying to get the node value and the key attribute to a list, like:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Option");
                key = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                value = reader.Value;

                if(key.Length > 0 && value.Length > 0)
                    categoryList.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
```

So, for the first Option I should get a Key-Value pair of <"category_advokater","Advokater">

But when adding to list I have mixed values of current/previous lines. Where am I getting wrong?

Thx in advance!

/snedker

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlReader? If you can use LINQ to XML instead, it's likely to make your life simpler.

Comment: PS: also tried with 

    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Option"))

without luck.

Comment: Hi Jon,

I could do many things that would make this work. Parse the outer xml, xpath...and so on. But now I REALLY want for this reader to work. Just because.  :-)

Comment: Have you tried reading the attribute value *before* reading the inner XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `LINQ to XML`:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var options = xmlDocument.Descendants("Option")
            .ToDictionary(x => (string)x, x => (string)x.Attribute("Key"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Must admit it is beautifully short! :)

Regards /Snedker

Comment: @MortenSnedker that's the beauty of LINQ to XML :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reader is much faster and allow you to process the xml files partially.

Try this code snippet instead.  ReadInnerXml advanced the read pointer to the next element.  If you don't skip the next read in the while statement, you will end up skipping an element unintentionally.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(text))) {
bool skipRead = false;
while (skipRead || reader.Read()) {
    skipRead = false;
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Option") {
        string key = reader.GetAttribute("Key");
        string value = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        skipRead = true;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. I just missed that each read actually performs a movement of the pointer of the reader. So I missed a beat.

Thx.